# Scala Newbie Multiple Files

Tags: file, class, scala, program-entry-point

I am new to Scala, and I cannot seem to find this information.  Currently I have 2 files:  ClassA.scala and MyMain.scala.  When I run 
`>scalac *.scala` it compiles both files perfectly fine.  However, when I run `> scala MyMain.scala` I get an error saying "not found: type ClassA".  Is there anything special I have to do to include a class in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have both classes on your classpath.  The "scala MyMain.scala" puts the MyMain.scala on the classpath, but not the ClassA.  `scala MyMain.scala -classpath ClassA.scala` should do the trick.
See [the getting started page for more details.](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166)

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell scala the classpath to the classes you are trying to load. You can do this with `scala -classpath` or the shorter `scala -cp`. So, for your example if the class files are in the current directory it would be `scala -cp . MyMain`. If you need to add more paths to the classpath you can separate them with a colon. e.g. `scala -cp .:dir:otherdir MyMain`.